# I don't understand why this Ruby on Rails code for f.select with options_from_collection_for_select does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie to Ruby (2.2.3) on Rails (4.2.4) and am trying some new code out. When I enter the Code below I get the following error.

Code:

```
     <%= f.select (:food_preference_id,
     options_from_collection_for_select(FoodPreference.all, :id, :name),
     {:prompt => 'Please Choose'}, {:class => "form-control"})  
     %>
```

Error:

```
      > syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

The error refers to the comma after :food_preference_id.

But when I type in the code without the brackets (as follows) it works

```
<%= f.select :food_preference_id,
 options_from_collection_for_select(FoodPreference.all, :id, :name),
 {:prompt => 'Please Choose'}, 
 {:class => "form-control"}  
%>
```

I don't understand why the code works without the brackets and does not work with the brackets. Can someone help me understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have **space** between method name and *bracket*.

```
f.select (:food_preference_id
        ^^
```

Write the code

```
 <%= f.select(:food_preference_id,
     options_from_collection_for_select(FoodPreference.all, :id, :name),
     {:prompt => 'Please Choose'}, {:class => "form-control"})  
 %>
```

Comment: Thanks Arup. That worked. Don't know how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Great catch, Arup!

For the OP, the thing to understand is that `.select` is a method call on the form builder object (`f`) created by your `form_for :object do |f|` statement. (Or whatever variation you are using.)

When calling methods using parameters (or arguments, whichever you prefer) contained within parentheses, the initial parenthesis must immediately follow the method name. So, as Arup points out,

```
this.is(:okay)
```

but

```
this.is (:not_okay)
```

You are not required, however, to use parentheses. So,

```
this.is :also_okay
```

Comment: jvillian thanks for the elaboration. Ruby has so many ways of expressing itself, it becomes easy for the rookie to overlook the fundamentals, thinking that "hey is this another way to express this, that I am not aware of?". 

 I Love Ruby on Rails but of course!

Comment: Sure thing. I've been working in RoR for quite a while and still learn something new just about every day. Please remember to mark an answer and upvote as you see fit.